# An application bundle was not found at the provided path. Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle

Tags: ios, xcode, watchos

I am facing this error while trying to run WatchOS app on simulator.
`An application bundle was not found at the provided path. Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.`

**Error Detail is as followed**

```
Simulator device returned an error for the requested operation.
Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain
Code: 2
Failure Reason: An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Recovery Suggestion: Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2024-01-08 13:24:30 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = "_IDEInstalliPhoneSimulatorWorker";
    SimCallingSelector = "installApplication:withOptions:error:";
    bundleURL = "file:///Users/abdullahshahid_1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SIMOSA-hdnvefmzxxdlwqagsrxeojmlbnje/Build/Products/Debug-watchos/Jazz%20World%20Watch%20App.app";
}
--
Failed to install the requested application
Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain
Code: 2
Failure Reason: An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Recovery Suggestion: Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
User Info: {
    bundleURL = "file:///Users/abdullahshahid_1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SIMOSA-hdnvefmzxxdlwqagsrxeojmlbnje/Build/Products/Debug-watchos/Jazz%20World%20Watch%20App.app";
}
--

Event Metadata: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "Watch7,4";
    "device_osBuild" = "10.2 (21S364)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.watchsimulator";
    "dvt_coredevice_version" = "355.7.6";
    "dvt_mobiledevice_version" = "1643.40.14.100.2";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = "x86_64";
    "operation_duration_ms" = 28;
    "operation_errorCode" = 2;
    "operation_errorDomain" = NSPOSIXErrorDomain;
    "operation_errorWorker" = "_IDEInstalliPhoneSimulatorWorker";
    "operation_name" = IDERunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 3;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 1;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.watchsimulator";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 16384;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_structuredConsoleMode" = 1;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphonesimulator17.2";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "17.2";
    "sdk_variant" = iphonesimulator;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 14.1 (Build 23B74)
Xcode 15.1 (22502) (Build 15C65)
Timestamp: 2024-01-08T18:24:30+05:00
```

The build succeeds but the path at which build is saved and the path from which Xcode tries to run on Watch simulator are different.

**Actual build path**: `file:///Users/abdullahshahid_1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SIMOSA-hdnvefmzxxdlwqagsrxeojmlbnje/Build/Products/Debug-watchsimulator/Jazz%20World%20Watch%20App.app`

**Xcode is looking at path**: `file:///Users/abdullahshahid_1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SIMOSA-hdnvefmzxxdlwqagsrxeojmlbnje/Build/Products/Debug-watchos/Jazz%20World%20Watch%20App.app`

**Difference**: Build is saved in `Debug-watchsimulator` folder but Xcode tries to install from `Debug-watchos`

I think Xcode uses path from `TARGET_TEMP_DIR` but I don't know how to make it correct.

Do anyone know how to fix this?

I tried to clean build folder, clear derived data folder, restart Macbook and restart xcode. But couldn't succeed.
The solutions I found on stack overflow are for React Native but nothing specifically for native iOS.

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be a bug in Xcode 15.1 (and it's still unresolved in Xcode 15.2). Quote from the [Xcode 15.2 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-15_2-release-notes):

> ### Devices
>
> #### Known issues
>
> Running a WatchApp that requires the companion iOS app to be installed will result in the error “An application bundle was not found at the provided path” when the run destination is set to a Watch via iPhone Simulator pair. (119640671)
>
> **Workaround:** Select a singular Watch Simulator run destination and then Run.

Another workaround is to use an older version of Xcode (like 15.0.1).

Comment: Any idea what "select a singular watch simulator run destination" means? Isn't that what's failing?

Comment: @johnny, in the list of run destinations, there's a section named "iOS simulators" with watches paired to iPhone simulators and a section named "watchOS simulators" with singular Watch simulators. However I'm not sure if that really can help when the watch app requires the iPhone companion app to run on a paired iPhone. In that case downgrading to Xcode 15.0.1 seems the best option.

Comment: Yep, switching to a simulator that didn't explicitly mention a paired iphone sim seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround is to create a symbolic link on the following folder:

`/Xcode/DerivedData/<YOUR_APP>/Build/Products/` enter to that path in the Terminal

And run:

`ln -s Debug-watchsimulator Debug-watchos`

You'll need to do the same if you Clean the build folder or Rebuild the app.

Reference: https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/743221#775164022

Answer (score 1):

It appears to have been fixed in Xcode 15.3 that has been released on March 5th.

[From the 15.3 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-15_3-release-notes):

> ### Devices
>
> #### Resolved Issues
>
> Fixed: Running a WatchOS app that requires the companion iOS app to be installed will result in the error “An application bundle was not found at the provided path” when the run destination is set to a Watch via iPhone Simulator pair. (119640671)